# How to run a build from a specific old tag in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab, maven

I can build from a specific old tag in teamity.
Screenshot:
[image]

How to run a build from a specific old tag in gitlab ci?

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s maven_settings.xml --batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"

stages:
  - build
  - release
  - build-tag

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install -PRPM -U

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - eval $(ssh-agent)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - git config user.name "$PUSH_USER_NAME"
    - git config user.email "$PUSH_USER_EMAIL"
    - git checkout master
    - git reset --hard origin/master
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean release:prepare -Dresume=false -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DdryRun=false -Dmaven.test.skip=true
  when: manual

build-tag:
  stage: build-tag
  script:
    - git checkout master
    - git pull
    - git reset --hard $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install -PRPM -U
  when: manual
```

build-tag i dont see in pipeline

How to run a build from a specific old tag in gitlab ci?

[image]

Comment: Your pipeline is somehow messed up. You are not supposed to take care of which code-revision you are building on in the jobs. the whole git-stuff seems wrong to me.
Gitlab takes care of the code itself and always provides a clean codebase to all jobs. if you want to carry over artifacts from previous jobs you should use *artifacts* and *dependencies* https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the project

- go to *CI / CD* -> *Pipelines*
- press *Run Pipeline*
- under *Create for* choose the branch or tag you want to run the pipeline for
- press *Create Pipeline*

Now to trigger a manual Job you can use the jobs of the recently created pipeline.